# Turn off $(document).load

Tags: jquery

I have...

```
$(document).load("Hi",function CheckHi() {
    // Do Stuff
 });
```

How do I stop `Hi` from running? I want to say...

```
$(window).off("Hi");
```

but I know this isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

```
$(document).unbind('load');
```

I'm not really sure what `"Hi"` is doing there, though - there isn't a string argument in [the `.load()` signature](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), and it might even result in jQuery thinking you mean [the other `.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (though I haven't tested). If you want to refer to the function again to unbind it, you want to name it outside the method call:

```
function checkHi() {
    // Do Stuff
}

$(document).load(checkHi);
// later...
$(document).unbind('load', checkHi);
```